# Invalid patch path with AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-api-gateway

I am looking to rename some API Gateway API Keys that were kicked out automatically and named horribling. I tried using a patch op but I receive the following.

```
$ aws --region $REGION --profile $PROFILE apigateway update-api-key \
--api-key $KEY --patch-operations op=replace,path=/name,value=MessengerAPI

A client error (BadRequestException) occurred when calling the UpdateApiKey operation: 
Invalid patch path  '/name' specified for op 'replace'. Must be one of: 
[/description, /enabled]
```

Evidently this is not the way to do it? Is there another way to rename  keys that have already been generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is currently no way to update the name of the API key. But I agree that this is suboptimal. We will look into it and try to address this issue, but cannot commit to a timeline.

I will update this post when we have more information.

Thanks,

Jurgen, API Gateway

Comment: Plus one and accepted, thanks Jurgen please keep me in the loop on development.

Comment: Hi, we pushed the update to our production stack and you should now be able to the name of the API Key